# Trigger tool window vsix extension on tfs check-in event

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, vsix, tfs-events

I want to load a tool window extension when we click check in button in team explorer window. Can anyone suggest how can we achieve this?

Comment: you can disable check in button and create a custom button, which can load a tool window pane and execute check in action.

Comment: I want to handle it in check in event handler, but the problem here is I am not able to catch that event from my code

Comment: @ZhanglongWu-MSFT, Could you explain it how to do that?